# Spinlocks in single processor and multi processor

Tags: synchronization, kernel, multiprocessing, spinlock

I read and studied how spinlocks work. Now I have a question which I can't find an exhaustive answer to:

how do they work in a UP (uni-processor) environment and in a SMP (symmetric multi processor) environment? What are the differences and problems?

Comment: i want to learn how exactly spinlock is implemented can you mention the source you referred to learn about it? it would be of great help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spinlocks are essentially useless in UP case. They will just burn their time slice. They would better sleep in UP. In case of SMP spinlocks *may* be preferred over sleeping, if expected wait time is lower than average time that is needed to get time slice again for this thread.

Answering your question "how do they work"? Exactly the same everywhere, just spending CPU time in their time slice.

Comment: Interesting, what about kernel threads? They don't have time-slices I suppose, do they?

Comment: @JohnnyPauling as far as I know (not 100% sure) kernel threads are regular threads in terms of time slicing, just with higher priority. Theoretically you can design OS where kernel can pause scheduling, but I am not sure if it is possible/used in major OSes.

Comment: I'm not a kernel expert so this is something new to me.. do OSes like linux/windows/OSX really use time slicing even for kernel threads?

Comment: @JohnnyPauling I think you have confusion over terms. You mean something different by kernel thread, I think by kernel thread you mean "system thread", but actually kernel threads is something different: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#Processes.2C_kernel_threads.2C_user_threads.2C_and_fibers

Comment: @JohnnyPauling and yes, apparently ALL threads are scheduled indeed, even system threads.

Comment: @Andrey depends on the priority level of scheduler. If the running piece of code is at least the same priority as the scheduler, it won't be preempted. For example, in Windows acquiring spinlock in Kernel will result in this effect - the critical section won't be preempted.

Comment: @icepack what do you mean by "same priority as the scheduler"? You imply that scheduler has priority?

Comment: @Andrey scheduler is process/thread running in the background. Just like any other thread it has an associated priority (if we talk in Windows Kernel terms - IRQL)

Comment: @icepack we are talking about different priorities, check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100(v=vs.85).aspx and there is a comment below that shows the confusion

Comment: @icepack http://asher2003.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/interrupt-level-vs-thread-priority/

Comment: @Andrey Yes, there is some confusion in this topic. I was referring to the Kernel priorities (the ones your second link describes). Scheduler runs at Dispatch level (== IRQL level 2 in your link) and if some code runs at this level at least, it will never be preempted (can happen to Kernel-mode code only)